# Iphone file I/O operation and file structure

Tags: iphone

I want to write a iphone SDK program to download and upload files from server. Server application is written in php.
But I m confusing following points in client application.

1) How can I download the file from server
2) How can I store it in iphone (accessing iphone file system)
3) How can I display all file in a directory to the users.

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create an [NSURL](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSURL *  theURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://foo.bar/whatever.php"];
```

Fetch the data with [NSData](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSData * theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: theURL];
```

Save it to a file with the same NSData object

```
NSString * theFolder = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString * theFileName = [theFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFile.txt"]
[theData writeToFile:theFileName atomically:true];
```

Use [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:) to list the files in the folder

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray * filesInFolderStringArray = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:theFolder error:error];
```

This will give you an array of NSStrings with the names of the files in the folder.